# Can I call a function or variables within a realm query?

Tags: react-native, realm

Is there any way to call a function or a variable within a realm query such as this? The _getDate() function can't seem to be called within the filtered

```
realm.objects('Round').filtered('id !== {_getDate()}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following code? Use string template syntax (Backtick instead quote and `${_getDate()}`.) Also, Realm's query syntax is not same as JavaScript. It doesn't have `!==` operator. Use `!=`.

```
realm.objects('Round').filtered(`id != ${_getDate()}`)
```